# Python urllib.urlretrieve gif image - loading meta information failed

Tags: python, urllib

very simple code:

```
import urllib
data = urllib.urlretrieve('http://www.python.org/pics','pythonHi.gif'
```

executing this, the image gets downloaded to my hard drive allright, but when i try to open it i get this error:

```
Loading ‘pythonHi.gif’ failed
Loading meta information failed.
```

I did try multiple programms to open my gif image.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Because you omit the image filename from the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `urllib` correctly, first param is the url to the element you want to download, second is the local file name under which the object can be found. It is perfectly explained on [`urllib.urlretrieve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) documentation.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> data = urllib.urlretrieve('http://www.python.org/pics/pythonHi.gif','pythonHi.gif')
```